# Pass a parameter from parent to child ASP GridView (C# codebehind)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am nesting three GridViews where each is dependent on the one before. I have the asp structure done and each is pulling from their respective data sources (asp:SqlDataSource in the aspx page). However, I can't figure out how to build the relationship so each pulls only the data related to the row that grid is nested on.

Examples:
[Similar but I don't need the drill downs](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

[Also very like what I'm looking for but this uses EntityDataSource](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/parent-child-view-in-a-single-table-with-gridview-control-on-asp-net-web-forms)

These examples have helped me to understand I will need the RowDataBound event to make this work. Great! But I can't figure out how to get the RowDataBound event to give me the unique parameter per row that must be run through my datasource that generates the data in the next GridView.

Codebehind:

```
    protected void CategoryGrid_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    //need to set my @catlinkulink parameter here
}

protected void CategoryGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


protected void CategoryOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView CategoryGridFC = DomainGrid.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("CategoryGrid") as GridView;
        string catlinkulink = CategoryGridFC.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values["catlinkulink"].ToString();

        TargetLinks.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = catlinkulink;
    }
}
```

Here is the data source from the aspx. This is for the grid that depends on the parameter pulled from each row of the category grid previous.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TargetLinks" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDB %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT t.ULink AS targetlinkulink, TargetDE
               FROM targetLink t
                  INNER JOIN IntTargets it ON t.TargetULink = it.ULink
                  INNER JOIN IntCategoryLink cl ON t.CatLinkULink = cl.ULink
                  WHERE t.CatLinkULink = @catlinkulink"
>
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="catlinkulink" DefaultValue="0" Type="Empty" Size="0" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" DbType="Object" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I apologize for how long this is, but I want to make sure I provide enough info to give a clear idea of what I'm trying to do. Thanks for any input you may have. I always learn a lot here--even if it's a different or better way to accomplish something.

I added the TargetLinks bit according to a suggestion below. I've also changed the FindControl for the CategoryGrid to look in the rows of the DomainGrid (its parent), but that's not working either.

> Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Here is the code for the nested GridViews.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="DomainGrid" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DomainGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    DataSourceID="DomainLinks" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="domainlinkulink">
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="DomainDE" ShowHeader="False" 
                SortExpression="DomainDE" HeaderStyle-Width="125">      
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="IntervCatDrop" runat="server" DataSourceID="IntervCatDD"
                 DataValueField="ulink" DataTextField="IntCategories">
                </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="AddIntCat" runat="server" Text="+" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="CategoryGrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="catlinkulink"
                DataSourceID="IntCategoryLinks" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                onselectedindexchanged="CategoryGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
                onrowdatabound="CategoryOnRowDataBound">
                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IntCategories" ShowHeader="False" 
                        SortExpression="Categories" HeaderStyle-Width="125"></asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="TargetDrop" runat="server" DataSourceID="TargetsDD"
                               DataValueField="ulink" DataTextField="TargetDE">
                               </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="AddTarget" runat="server" Text="+" />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>    

                  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="TargetGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="TargetLinks" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            DataKeyNames="targetlinkulink" onselectedindexchanged="TargetGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetDE" ShowHeader="false" SortExpression="TargetDE" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>            
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>





</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Set the asp:parameter value in the row bound event like this:
    TargetLinks.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = catlinkulink;

Comment: @R_Scott - what is the error you are getting, you just posted the code in the comment?

Comment: Sorry, I put the error in the comment and it was a mess so I updated the original post for readability. It's an "Object reference not set to instance..." error. Nothing as showing as problematic in VS so I'm trying to figure out why the datakey is not being passed in the row data bound event.

Comment: Probably you are looking for a gridview inside it's own row. Can you post the markup for the gridviews?

Comment: @afzalulh I've added the GridView code. You are correct, the grid I'm searching for with my FindControl is in a row of a parent GridView. I'm beginning to think I should just rethink this. I wanted it to work like a tree, which I don't think would be tough if the users didn't need each level to have multiple selections for each of the previous selections--too confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Do I need to find the control using the index of the parent grid or possibly iterate through each grid in nested loops?  Could I use something like DomainGrid.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("CategoryGrid")   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest to change `Parameter`, which looks wrong. Assuming `CatLinkULink` is a string field, I would change SelectParameters to this:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="catlinkulink" Type="String" DefaultValue=""  />
</SelectParameters>
```

And move the SqlDataSource inside the CategoryGrid, add a hidden field. Here's how the markup of CategoryGrid may look:

```
<asp:gridview id="CategoryGrid" runat="server" datakeynames="catlinkulink"
    datasourceid="IntCategoryLinks" autogeneratecolumns="false"
    onselectedindexchanged="CategoryGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
    onrowdatabound="CategoryOnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IntCategories" ShowHeader="False"
            SortExpression="Categories" HeaderStyle-Width="125"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="TargetDrop" runat="server" DataSourceID="TargetsDD"
                    DataValueField="ulink" DataTextField="TargetDE">
                </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="AddTarget" runat="server" Text="+" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="TargetGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="TargetLinks" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="targetlinkulink" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TargetGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TargetDE" ShowHeader="false" SortExpression="TargetDE" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCatlinkulink" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("catlinkulink") %>' />
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TargetLinks" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDB %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT t.ULink AS targetlinkulink, TargetDE
                                FROM targetLink t
                                    INNER JOIN IntTargets it ON t.TargetULink = it.ULink
                                    INNER JOIN IntCategoryLink cl ON t.CatLinkULink = cl.ULink
                                    WHERE t.CatLinkULink = @catlinkulink">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="catlinkulink" Type="String" DefaultValue=""  />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

And in the code I would set the parameter:

```
protected void CategoryOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView TargetGrid = e.Row.FindControl("TargetGrid") as GridView;
        HiddenField hdnCatlinkulink = e.Row.FindControl("hdnCatlinkulink") as HiddenField;
        SqlDataSource TargetLinks = e.Row.FindControl("TargetLinks") as SqlDataSource;

        if (TargetGrid != null && hdnCatlinkulink != null && TargetLinks != null)
        {
            string catlinkulink = hdnCatlinkulink.Value;
            TargetLinks.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = catlinkulink;
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I did not test the code above, it may needs to tweak.

Comment: I'm still unable to make it work. I'm sure it's my failing, though. I'm going to keep toying with it to see what I can figure out, but I believe I have to drop it for now and find a simpler path for me albeit probably many more clicks for the users. Either way, the deadline looms so I have to move on. I appreciate the help, and I do believe it will all be beneficial so thank you again.

Comment: If it's ok, you can send me the source.I will look at them, suggest any working solutions by tomorrow morning.

Comment: I finally made some progress. I should say you made some progress since it was your code suggestion. I had moved the sqldatasource into the gridview, but I had it placed in the wrong level of the parent/child nest. Thank you so much for your too-generous offer to work on this for me. I hate to have someone else do my work for me, but I was getting very frustrated. I think I should be able to use this for the nest above category as well and be okay. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score -1):

you can set a textbox in a hiden div to get the value when grid selected event fired.
and then you can set parameter to this textbox.text in sqldatasource.
This is what I done for this situation